# What is Google's purpose from naming convention for android versions? Who are their target?

Tags: conventions, google, names

Google tend to choose attractive names for their android versions like Jelly Beans, Kitkat, Ice cream sandwich and so on. What is their main purpose from these naming conventions? Does that related to attracting more people from different groups?

**EDIT**
More specifically I'd like to know why they choose names like Jelly Bean, Ice cream. What's their goal?

Comment: I've already read that article. Main part of my question is related to Google and nothing else. I would love to know why they choose names like jelly bean, ice cream.

Comment: Try asking on android.SE or on a Google forum.

Comment: Why a company chooses to name their product something isn't really a user experience question. That's like asking why Burger King chose that name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not going to get an answer to this unless Google decides to reveal it one day. To [quote this article](http://edition.cnn.com/2011/TECH/innovation/02/04/google.honeycomb.android.names/)

> Google doesn't want to explain.
>
> "It's kind of like an internal team thing, and we prefer to be a
>   little bit -- how should I say -- a bit inscrutable in the matter,
>   I'll say," said Randall Sarafa, a Google spokesman. "The obvious thing
>   is that, yeah, the Android platform releases, they go by dessert names
>   and by alphabetical order for the most part." "For the most part"
>   because two versions of Android, 2.0 and 2.1, were both called Eclair.
>   And because Google won't say what it called the first two versions of
>   Android, which you can assume started with "A" and "B." "As far as the
>   public knows, it started with Cupcake," Sarafa said

This is also an [interesting article](http://hubpages.com/hub/Cupcake-Donut-Eclair-Froyo-Gingerbread-Honeycomb-Android-OS-Version-Codenames-and-Why) on the names used on Google's operating systems

There **might** also be  a demographic reason behind the name of the sweet chosen to. To quote this [article](http://www.foxnews.com/tech/2013/09/04/google-names-new-android-os-after-chocolate-bar/)

> Podhajsky said that Kit Kat's jingle is a good fit for people taking a
>   break to look at their smartphones or tablets. She added that the deal
>   appeals to Hershey because Android hits the sweet spot of Kit Kat
>   eaters, who are typically between the ages of 18 and 34.
>
> "Kit Kat consumers are young, vibrant consumers of candy and chocolate
>   bars, and that's a nice match with Android," Podhajsky said.

However it could just be **a matter of personal preference** as well

> The Kit Kat name was unexpected since tech pundits have speculated for
>   months that the next operating system would be called Key Lime Pie.
>   Marc Vanlerberghe, director of Android Marketing, said the name was
>   chosen because Kit Kat bars have been a "**favorite go-to snack among
>   the team since the early days of Android**."

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that it's due to how broad the category is for expansion purposes (each version). Marketing may also come into play as the name choices are playful and adds a personality to the OS's. The names are also easy to recognize and memorize

Answer (score 0):

Each name uses starts with a progresses letter of the alphabet.

Ironically, if you'd just `googled google android names list` then the [top result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history) says:

> Since April 2009, Android versions have been developed under a codename and released according to alphabetical order: Cupcake (1.5), Donut (1.6), Eclair (2.0–2.1), Froyo (2.2–2.2.3), Gingerbread (2.3–2.3.7), Honeycomb (3.0–3.2.6), Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0–4.0.4), Jelly Bean (4.1–4.3), and KitKat (4.4).

Google have chosen to name their releases after desserts and sweet snacks. [Intel named many CPUs after rivers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_codenames). It's just a way of expressing a little bit of corporate personality.